# Stochastic processes, indistinguishability

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes

This may be a fundamental question on a theory of stochastic processes.

Let $X=\{X_t\}_{t \ge 0}$ be an $\mathbb{R}^d$-valued stochastic process on a (sufficiently nice) filtered probability space (we denote by $P$ the probability measure). We assume that $X$ is right-continuous and has finite left limits. We moreover assume that for any bounded continuous function $u\colon \mathbb{R}^d \to \mathbb{R}$ and any $t>0$
\begin{align}
P\left[ u(X_t)=u(X_{t-}) \right]=1.
\end{align}
Here, $u(X_{t-})=\lim_{s \nearrow t}u(X_s)(=u(\lim_{s \nearrow t}X_s)$).

**My question.**

Can we show that $P\left[X_t=X_{t-}\text{ for any }t\ge0 \right]=1$?

We note that $\{u(X_t)\}_{t \ge 0}$ is right continuous and $\{u(X_{t-})\}_{t \ge 0}$ is left continuous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathsf{P})=([0,1],\mathcal{B}_{[0,1]},\lambda)$, where $\lambda$ is the Lebesgue measure and let $X_t(\omega):=1\{t\ge \omega\}$, $t\in [0,1]$. Then
$$
\mathsf{P}(X_t\ne X_{t-})=\lambda(\{t\})=0
$$
for any $t\in [0,1]$. However,
$$
\mathsf{P}(X_t \text{ is continuous on } [0,1])=0.
$$